# How do I proceed in proving that $\cos 20^o\cos 40^o\cos 60^o\cos 80^o = \frac{1}{16}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have taken the value of $\cos 20^o$ to be $x$.

Now,
$$\cos 20^o\cos 40^o\cos 60^o\cos 80^o = \dfrac{\cos 20^o}{2}\cos(40^o)\cos(80^o)$$
$$=\dfrac{x}{2}\Bigg( \dfrac{\cos(40^o + 80^o) + \cos(40^o - 80^o)}{2} \Bigg)$$
$$=\dfrac{x}{2}\Bigg( \dfrac{\dfrac{-1}{\text{ }2} + \cos 40^o}{2} \Bigg) = \dfrac{x}{4}\Bigg( \dfrac{-1}{\text{ }2}+2x^2-1 \Bigg)$$
$$=\dfrac{x}{8}(4x^2-3) = \dfrac{4x^3-3x}{8}$$

Can this even be continued (I mean to ask if this method will lead me any further)? If yes, how do I continue it?

Thanks!

PS : Please don't provide alternatives, I want to try them myself first. This question is only for the sake of asking if this method can be continued and it if can be, then how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are one step away from the final answer. Use the fact that
$$\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$$
and the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank You! One soft-question though, should I memorize a few identities of $\sin(nx)$, $\cos(nx)$ for $n \in \Bbb N$ or just derive them at the time of use? I think I should go with the latter.

Comment: Trig identities for $n\leqslant 3$ often come in handy. I think you should remember them. You can always derive them if you forget though :)